# My django project is working noormally with raspberry connected to screen but when I run it with vnc viewer it returns a problem?

Tags: pi-2, vnc

I used vnc viewer to use my raspberry . I have a Django project that contains an application which shows a curve it is working normally but when I run it with vnc it says application not found and the page becomes blank .

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "run it with vnc".

Comment: when I write in my teminal tha command python manage.py runserver using thhe screen and  the keyboard... and I access to my application it returns a curve whereas when I do the same using vnc it returns a blank page . I hope it's clearer

Comment: no, it is not. Also, please make an effort to write, if not grammatically correct English, at least free of obvious typing mistakes. It's elementary manners.

Comment: ok thhank yo for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how applications write to the screen certain VNC servers may not be able to "see" the application.

I saw RealVNC at the Raspberry Pi birthday celebrations bragging how their application (free for Pi users but requires registration) can handle many of these including Minecraft Pi.

https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/raspberrypi/